# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away with DBngin

Tags: mysql

I'm running `MySQL` with `DBngin` and i get this error. It seems that laravel can't even connect to the database.

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away`

I saw that increasing the 'max_allowed_packet` the issue can be solved but i haven't found a way to do that in my case.

i downloaded `mysql-client` and after i connected to my database, i tried to set the `max_allowed_packet`

```
set global max_allowed_packet=16000000;
```

But for some reason it doesn't change, I checked that with

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

This can also be changed in the `my.cnf` file but because i am running `MySQL` with `DBngin` i couldn't find the configuration file. I know that i can set a custom configuration file in `DBngin` but i'm not sure what else i should include in that file besides the `max_allowed_packet` in order to make it work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: If Linux, issue a `mysqladmin --help` command ..  It will display the manual page PLUS helpful items like where your `my.cnf` is located. IE my output looks like: `Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`

Comment: i use macOS Big Sur

Comment: You should still be able to issue the `mysqladmin` command in MacOs

Comment: i haven't installed mysql, but i run dbngin which runs mysql, and i can't find a default my.cnf in the dbngin folders.

Comment: Somewhere like `/Users/<user_name>/Library/Application\ Support/com.tinyapp.DBngin/Engines/mysql/`  OR  right click on the MySQL service, and click "Edit" -- It should display the path.

Comment: If those both fail ..  open a terminal, cd to machine root: `cd /`  --  And issue a `find` command `find / -type f -name 'my.cnf'`

Comment: Nowhere to be found